# How to write/read data to/from structure array using write/fread?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, fwrite, fread

I have spent quite a lot time attempting to find a solution how to write and read structure to/from file and completely get stuck.

The code should be very simple, but I think I've missed quite important details about `fwrite`/`fread`. I think write is working but I am not completely sure. Once I try to read into array I get segmentation fault error on the `k=1`.

I would be ultimately happy if someone could guide me in what direction should I move further.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
char matrikl[6];
char shortName[6];
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;
int value4;
int money;
}xStudent;

int calcMoney(int,int,int,int);

int main(void)
{
int i=0;
printf("How much students to insert!\n");
scanf("%i",&i);
    struct Student S[i];

for (int var = 0; var < i; ++var) {
    printf("insert student data\n");
    printf("Matriklinumber\n");
    scanf("%s", S[var].matrikl);
    printf("Student name\n");
    scanf("%s", S[var].shortName);
    printf("Insert values!\n");
    scanf("%i%i%i%i",&S[var].value1,&S[var].value2,&S[var].value3,&S[var].value4);
    S[var].money=calcMoney(S[var].value1,S[var].value2,S[var].value3,S[var].value4);;
}

FILE*sourcefile;
sourcefile=fopen("text.txt","ab+");

for (int var = 0; var < i; ++var) {
    fwrite(&S[var],sizeof(struct Student),1,sourcefile);
}
fclose(sourcefile);


sourcefile=fopen("text.txt","rb+");
struct Student A[i];

if (sourcefile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
          else
          {
                  int k=0;
                  while (fgetc(sourcefile) != EOF) {
                  fread(&A[k],sizeof(struct Student),1,sourcefile);
                  k++;
                  }
          }
fclose(sourcefile);
return 0;
}

int calcMoney(int xvalue1, int xvalue2, int xvalue3, int xvalue4)
{
int Sum = xvalue1+xvalue2+xvalue3+xvalue4;
if(Sum==20)
    return 100;
else
    if(Sum>=16 && Sum<20)
        return 75;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but this should fix your problem.

```
for (int var = 0; var < i; ++var) {
    fwrite(&S[i], sizeof(struct Student), 1, sourcefile);
}
```

The argument 1 in `fwrite` after the `sizeof` statement indicates you only want to add one Student at a time.

Please see the doc for `fwrite`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

And also:

```
          while (fgetc(sourcefile) != EOF) {
          fread(&A[k], sizeof(struct Student), 1, sourcefile);
          k++;
          }
```

Please see the doc for `fread`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

I know it's the cplusplus website, but it's the only place I could find good docs on the functions.

Also, the below array initializes to 0 elements:

```
struct Student A[k];
```

You may want to try managing a linked list for this instead.

Might end up looking something like:

```
struct StudentList {
    struct Student* student;
    struct StudentList* next;
};
```

```
struct StudentList* students = NULL;

while(!feof(sourcefile)) {
    struct StudentList* newlink = malloc(sizeof(struct StudentList));
    newlink->student = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    newlink->next = NULL;

    fread(newlink->student, sizeof(struct Student), 1, sourcefile); 

    if(NULL != students) {
        struct StudentList* iter;
        for(iter=students;
            NULL != iter->next;
            iter = iter->next); // iterate to last link

        iter->next = newlink; // add new link to the end
    } else students = newlink; // add new link to the beginning
}
```

Then to free your list, just use something like:

```
struct StudentList* iter, *head;
for(iter=students;
    NULL != iter;)
{
    head = iter;
    free(iter->student);
    free(iter);
    iter = head;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I have corrected fwrite function arguments and it seems ok but still cannot read from file. Second array element symbols in debugger does not correspond to first one.

Comment: @user3369281 Can you update your question with the code as it stands now so I can get a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: @user3369281 Please read my post carefully when it comes to the arguments of `fwrite` and `fread`, also k is 0 when you initialize A, so you're making an array with 0 elements, and adding to k later doesn't add elements to your array. You will need to either dynamically allocate elements to your array, or use a fixed sized array. Included in my answer is an example of using a dynamically allocated linked list.

Comment: I have updated the code. Also corrected some of my silly mistakes :).

Comment: @user3369281 The reason your read code is off is because `while (fgetc(sourcefile) != EOF) {`. You're getting a character from the stream, which increments your position in the file, instead use `while(!feof(sourcefile)) {` and it should work as intended.

Comment: I am not yet familiar with memory management (mean * symbols). This is my next step in c. :)

Comment: @user3369281 Oh, not a problem, the code is there for anyone that may find it helpful, now or in the near future.

Comment: This is incredibly cool. Thank you David Otano. I should have been post here much earlier :).

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the declaration of array A.

```
struct Student A[k];
```

k=0; so you are getting error since A[1] or so the array is not defined.
change the declaration to

```
struct Student A[i];
```

then it should run if rest of code and syntax is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fix fwrite line to:

```
fwrite(&S[i], sizeof(struct Student), 1, sourcefile);
```